# Application For Quick Translation of Selected Text? (2018)

Tags: 18.04, tools, translation

I need a tool that runs in the background so that I can highlight a text (eg from PDF files) and press a hotkey to have instant translation of it, in a small popup window. It should be using Google Translate as a main dictionary.
Just like QTranslate in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **goldendict** and then activate "scan popup feature".